# Which is better? mysql's LIKE or REGEXP?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sql-like

I have this named_scope with a LIKE and NOT LIKE in one statement. Is this faster in terms of execution compared to using REGEXP?

```
named_scope :order_search, :order => "name LIKE '%urgent%' AND name NOT LIKE '%not urgent%' DESC, created_at DESC"
```

Comment: better use `RLIKE` or `REGEXP`

Answer (score 5):

It's milliseconds difference, unnoticable. Unless you're dealing with an extremely high amount of traffic, it won't matter.

If you're experiencing performance issues with your approach, it's likely because your table has a large amount of rows. The bottle-neck isn't LIKE then (and MySQL also supports REGEXP) but your table structure.

In any case, you should read up on [MySQL Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html) and [MySQL Fulltext Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

Answer (score 2):

In so far as I'm aware, MySQL's `LIKE` will use Boyer–Moore in this case, so there might be a slight advantage for `LIKE`.

It'll be negligible compared to using a trigger that would store the whole expression in an `is_urgent` field however. You could then add an index on `(is_urgent, created_at)`.

Comment: That would depend on his repartition. If there are few urgent items the planner will use the index.

Comment: It'll be filesort if he fetches everything, but it'll be an simple index read/sort if he paginates -- and it's presumable that he does.

Comment: he's order_search query everything,even simple query use the index,but the filesort does not avoid

Answer (score 1):

your query is not left most query, it could not use index
so the like and regexp are same